# convert from AWT and JAI for android

Tags: java, android, awt, jai

I have a problem about converting java project to android. What makes
me confuse is the equivalent to SampleModel, ColorModel, WritableRaster,
and TiledImage for android? Here is the snipped code:

```
SampleModel sampleModel = RasterFactory.createBandedSampleModel(
               DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, 4 * numXTiles, 4* numYTiles, 1);
   ColorModel colorModel = PlanarImage.createColorModel(sampleModel);
   WritableRaster decWRaster = RasterFactory.createWritableRaster(
               sampleModel, null);
   for (int j = 0; j < numYTiles; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numXTiles; i++) {
               int indexEnc = disEnc.readByte();
               if (indexEnc < 0) indexEnc = indexEnc + 128;
               System.out.print(indexEnc + " ");

               int[] codeWord = codeBook[indexEnc];
               decWRaster.setPixels(i * 4, j * 4, 4, 4, codeWord);
            }
         }
         TiledImage decTImage = new TiledImage(0, 0, 4 * numXTiles,
               4 * numYTiles, 0, 0, sampleModel, colorModel);
         decTImage.setData(decWRaster);
         JAI.create("FileStore", decTImage, decPath + "test4.bmp",
"BMP");
```

This code is for creating an image with int[] as the input, and tiling
each pixel to 4x4 box which width is numXTiles*4 and height is
numYTiles*4.

Can anyone help? many thx :)